# Javascript timer not working (Simple but I still need help)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little game, I want to set a timer for it for 1 second, yet I keep failing.

The timer makes the balance randomly jump from 0 to 13000 + some change.

```html
<script>
var satoshi = 0; var hash = 1;
</script>
<center>
  <h4>
    Hashs Per Second:
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write(hash)
    </script>
  </h4>
</center>
<center>
  <p id="cookiespersecond">Satoshis: 0</p>
</center>
<button onclick="minebtc()"><img src="kop.png" height=28 width=32>Mine BTC</button>
<button onclick="stop()"><img src="kop.png" height=28 width=32>Stop Mining BTC</button>

<script>
  function minebtc() {
    satoshi = satoshi + hash
    update()
  }

  function update() {
    document.getElementById('cookiespersecond').innerHTML = "Satoshis: " + satoshi;
    setTimeout(update, 3000)
    minebtc()
  }

  function stop() {

  }
</script>
```

Comment: You're hitting a stack overflow exception.  That almost always means you have one function calling itself *over and over*.  In this case, `minebtc` calls `update` which calls `minebtc` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your `RangeError` is caused by `minebtc` calling `update` and that one calling `minebtc` over and over again, without letting the code finish running (therefore allowing for other stuff to be inserted in the event loop). To fix this, you can simply call `minebtc` with a 0ms timer, this basically allows for other events to interleave their code between your mutual recursion.

```html
<script>
var satoshi = 0; var hash = 1;
</script>
<center>
  <h4>
    Hashs Per Second:
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write(hash)
    </script>
  </h4>
</center>
<center>
  <p id="cookiespersecond">Satoshis: 0</p>
</center>
<button onclick="minebtc()"><img src="kop.png" height=28 width=32>Mine BTC</button>
<button onclick="stop()"><img src="kop.png" height=28 width=32>Stop Mining BTC</button>

<script>

function minebtc() {
  satoshi = satoshi + hash;
  setTimeout(update, 3000);
}

function update() {
  document.getElementById('cookiespersecond').innerHTML = "Satoshis: " + satoshi;
  setTimeout(minebtc, 0)
}


  function stop() {

  }
</script>
```

Comment: @mahanlorik What do you want the code to do exactly ?

Comment: @mahanlorik The only thing wrong with your question's code from my point of view is that it throws a `RangeError` when run, what other requirements do you have ?

Comment: @mahanlorik edited my answer with what I think is what you want to achieve.